# Associated model isn't being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I'm a complete rails newbie, so forgive me if this is trivial.

I have an Inventory model that either belongs_to a Store or a Traveling Party:

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trader, :polymorphic => true
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :inventory, :as => :trader, :dependent => :destroy
end

class TravelingParty < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :travelers, :dependent => :destroy
    has_one :inventory, :as => :trader, :dependent => :destroy
    validates_presence_of :speed, :ration, :position
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :travelers, :reject_if => :reject_traveler, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventory, :allow_destroy => true

    def reject_traveler(attributes)
       attributes['profession'].blank? and attributes['name'].blank?
    end

end
```

I created a form that, when submitted, creates a Traveling Party and a number of Travelers. Now I'd like the form to also create an Inventory and initialize all the variables to 0. I know the following doesn't address variable initialization, but it doesn't even seem to put a row of null values into the Inventory database table.

```
class TravelingPartiesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @traveling_party = TravelingParty.new
        5.times do
            traveler = @traveling_party.travelers.build
        end
        @inventory = @traveling_party.inventory.create

    end

    def create
        @traveling_party = TravelingParty.new(params[:traveling_party])
        if @traveling_party.save
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully created traveling party and travelers."
            redirect_to '/store/'
        else
            flash[:error] = "Please specify a leader."
            redirect_to '/new/'
        end
    end

    def index
    end

end
```

For good measure, here is what the database schema looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111018224808) do

  create_table "inventories", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "ox"
    t.integer  "food"
    t.integer  "clothing"
    t.integer  "ammunition"
    t.integer  "money"
    t.integer  "axle"
    t.integer  "wheel"
    t.integer  "tongue"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "trader_id"
  end

  create_table "stores", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "location"
    t.integer  "priceScale"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

# Could not dump table "travelers" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'relations' for column 'traveling_party_id'

  create_table "traveling_parties", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "speed"
    t.integer  "ration"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Is there a reason the inventory database table isn't being affected at all? And once that works, what would be the best way to initialize a traveling_party.inventory to have all 0s? (i.e., values for ox, food, clothing, etc).

Comment: this looks suspicious: `# Could not dump table "travelers" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'relations' for column 'traveling_party_id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may because your inventories table does not include a 'trader_type'. This is required for polymorphic associations.

```
  create_table "inventories", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "trader_id"
    t.string   "trader_type"
  end
```

Edit:

To set all the values initially to 0, the best way would be to put a default value onto the fields in the table. (If you want it to always be initialized to 0 if there is no other option, otherwise they will default to nil)

I believe you can create a migration with

```
change_table(:inventories) do |t|
  t.change :ox, :integer, :default => 0
end
```

Comment: Thanks! We ended up implementing STI instead of polymorphism